# Clicking a link with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need help to open link while scraping the www.apartments.com website.The link is actually a pagination link that is populated by javascript/jquery.
Here is how the link looks like:

```
    <a class="pagination-link" data-page="2" href="#">2</a>
```

This my selenium script to find and click the link:

```
    pagination = browser.find_element_by_link_text('2')
    pagination.click()
```

Selenium does find the link and click. Another opened but it's not the page 2. I know that happens because the `href="#"` points to same page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to give full examples of your code and fully explain the errors you're getting. Having said that, here is my stab at what you should do. C# example, adjust as necessary:

Note: this is using a CSS selector, rather than link text

```
int pageNumber = 2;
IWebElement paginationLink = _webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".pagination-link[data-page='" + pageNumber + "']"));
paginationLink.Click();
```